# How do I create a user given amount of images (in PIL - Python)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a problem that should be easy to solve but I can't think of how to do it. Here is my code:

```py
image_1 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_2 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_3 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_4 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_5 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_6 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_7 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
image_8 = Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255))
```

However, I want to do this (create images and name them) a user given amount of times. How is this possible? Full code is here - https://github.com/LouisPi/flashcard_generator/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but when you have a variable number of similar things (you seem to have 8 images but maybe want more or fewer), you normally make a Python `list`... https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop or list comprehension. Something like:

```
images = []
for i in range(num_images):
    images.append(Image.new('RGB', (w//2, h//2), (255, 255, 255)))
```

Or for the comprehension:

```
images = [Image.new('RGB', (w//w, h//w), (255, 255, 255)) for i in range(num_images)]
```